# Logarithmic color scale not in base 10

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 3 numpy arrays I'm trying to plot in a scatter plot, where the data is visualised on a color scale.
This is the line I use for the plot.

```
plt.scatter(y1, x1, c = jm, s = 3, cmap = 'jet', marker = '.', linewidths = 0, norm = colors.LogNorm())
```

How do I plot this on a logarithmic color scale with a base other than 10?

Comment: log on one base is different from log on another base by a constant. So different bases wouldn't affect color scaling at all.